# Error in attribute route regex constraint in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I add the following route attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("add")]
[Route(@"{id:int}/{inn:regex(^[0-9]+$)}/incBalance:range(0,1)/{dateSet:datetime}/{dateNext:datetime}")]
public IActionResult Add(int id, string inn, int incBalance, DateTime dateSet, DateTime dateNext)
{
  ....
}
```

At execution time error occurs:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: The following errors occurred with attribute routing information:

Error 1:
For action: 'WebProject.Areas.DAS.Controllers.ReportController.Add'
Error: While processing template 'das/report/[action]/{id:int}/{inn:regex(^[0-9]+$)}/incBalance:range(0,1)/{dateSet:datetime}/{dateNext:datetime}', a replacement value for the token '0-9' could not be found. Available tokens: 'action, area, controller'.
```

I delete `regex(^[0-9]+$)` and everything works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use regex in an `RouteAttribute` you must escape `[` and `]` characters with `[[` and `]]`, because `[` and `]` is reserved for the controller parameters (action, controller and area) like in `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`.

**Update**: Same applies to `{` and `}` where you escape it with `{{` and `}}`, but this one is also valid for default routes you setup in `app.UseMvc( route => ... )`.